# Getting "ValueError: No Json object could be decoded" when running a Python MapReduce script via Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, json, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a simple python mapreduce script on Hadoop via streaming. The mapper part loads a json document, reads the text from a property and emits each word in the text with 1, to be later summed up by the reducer portion of the script. The code works perfectly fine outside Hadoop. Once submitted to Hadoop, the map fails with a "ValueError: No Json object could be decoded". The line of error is the one with the "json.loads()" function. I am completely stumped by this. The Hadoop ecosystem I'm trying to run on is the HortonWorks sandbox with Python 2.6.6 onboard. Did anybody else run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much fiddling around with the script, I found that the problem disappears when doing the following:

- Using `#!/usr/bin/env python2` at the top of the mapper and reducer files. This shebang specifically specifies version 2.X of the Python runtime to be used for execution.
- Using the following notation when issuing the Hadoop streaming command:

  `hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -files mapper.py,reducer.py -mapper 'python mapper.py' -reducer 'python reducer.py' -input <hdfs path to input file(s)> -output <hdfs path to output directory>`

After applying these modifications, the problem ceased to appear. Go figure!